# Angular Creating component at runtime and need to add data to it

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, angular8

I am using Angular 7/8 and I have some code with adds a new component so in the parent component I have:

PARENT COMPONENT

In the .ts file I have:

```
  @ViewChild(InjectDirective) injectComp: InjectDirective;

  constructor (private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}


  addComponent() {
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ChildComponent);
    const viewContainerRef = this.injectComp.viewContainerRef;
    viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
  }
```

And in the .html I have:

```
<button (click)="addComponent()">Add Component</button>
```

I also have a directive:

```
import { Directive, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appInject]'
})
export class InjectDirective {

  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {}

}
```

And finally the child component:

CHILD COMPONENT:

Then in the child component I have:

```
  export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('viewer') private viewer: ElementRef;

}
```

and in the html just:

```
<div>I AM A COMPONENT</div>
```

What I want to do is to pass data to the created child components so that each can have its own data.

How can I do this:

Comment: Try to create a `common service` to send data from parent to child OR use `@Output` decorator with `EventEmitter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `instance` property of `ComponentRef` returned by `viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);`

```js
  addComponent() {
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ChildComponent);
    const viewContainerRef = this.injectComp.viewContainerRef;
    const compRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    compRef.instance.someProperty = "some data";
  }
```

here is a working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lusfbj

Comment: But what if you want to create multiple components and not only one?